# Elements in Eclipse WindowBuilder Look Old

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, jframe

So, I'm making a window in WindowBuilder with Eclipse Photon, and this is the GUI:

[image: GUI]

It looks pretty normal. However, when I run the program, I get some Windows Vista-looking design:

[image: Windows Vista-looking design]

It used to show up regularly, but for some reason it has changed, any idea what triggered this, and how to get it back?

P.S Just so you know, in case this proves useful, I am using Eclipse Photon, but for personal reasons, I installed Eclipse Neon about twenty minutes ago. My thinking is maybe Eclipse Neon changed it during installation, is that right?

Comment: The Neon installation should not affect your Photon installation. What you see is a Java Swing GUI. Unfortunately, WindowBuilder does not support JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to fiddle with the look and feel with Swing [1]. You can also switch to SWT which uses the native widgets as much as possible instead of drawing each widget itself.

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html